# Normal for John the Ripper to fail to crack password after having successfully cracked it before?

Tags: john-the-ripper

The first two or three times I ran it, John the Ripper successfully cracked a password file with a single hashed password.  Since then, however, I've only been getting this result (with the same password file and JtR version):

> 0 password hashes cracked, 1 left

I tried removing the john.pot file, but that had no effect.

Any reason for this?

Comment: Same password or different passwords?

Comment: @schroeder Same password

Comment: Is it possible that you did something to impact GPU usage?

Comment: @user10216038 I seriously doubt it.  I'm on a virtual machine and this is literally the only thing I'm doing.  I'm curious, though.  How would GPU usage affect this?

Comment: Are you calling John with different arguments, or formatting the arguments differently? Can you double check to make sure John is reading the hash in the correct format (either through --format=<hash format> or what John is telling you it has detected the hash as in it's output). If you update your question with some example output and the specific arguments you are using to call john it would go a long way in helping you find the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP discovered the error being made.